# How creating a new object resets a particular value on windows form - C# Windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to understand a behavior of my program execution.

I have a windows form app that have 2 buttons, 'Initiate' and 'Increment'

The initiate button click method has a call to make a new object. The increment button click is associated with a function that increments by 5.

Initiate button click has this:

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Ball testObj = new Ball();
}
```

The function that increments the value is:

```
public void Increment()
{
    BallCount += 1;
}
```

BallCount is defined as auto-implemented property, like:

```
public int BallCount {get; private set;}
```

On my design form, I have a label to display ball count. Whenever, I click increment button on the form, that label text is updated with incremented value.

The increment button code is:

```
private void btnIncrement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
     testObj.Increment();
     lblStats.Text = testObj.ToString();
}
```

Now, when I run my program and when I click increment button multiple times, the label updates and display the incremented value, but when I click on initiate button after that, the label value resets to 0. Why does that happen? I am not resetting the BallCount value anywhere.

Comment: Where is `BallCount` defined?  What is its scope?

Comment: nvm.  You create a new `Ball` - the scope of `BallCount` is the `Ball`.

Comment: you've also done something very weird in your create button handler.  `testObj` is scoped to the function, but you use it later...?  Without a *complete* code sample you're kind of on your own here.

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

When you click Initiate button it recreates 
Ball testObj = new Ball();
and now since BallCount is scoped to testObj, it got refreshed as well and default value of Integer is zero and hence it will get back to zero.

If you want that BallCount should not be affected by Initiate button then make BallCount static

public static int BallCount {get; set;}

Answer (score -1):

1 - Since you want to set the label's text as `BallCount`'s value, you find its value by calling the instance's property `testObj.BallCount.ToString();`

2 - Also, for any and all of your form elements to find the `Ball's testObj` reference, you need to set it as a property in your form, like

```
public Ball testObj {get; set;}
```

Otherwise `btnIncrement_Click` won't find the instance `btnCreate_Click` made.

Comment: _"If you want to reference it through the testObj instance, remove its void qualifier"_ -- that statement makes no sense. `void` is the return type of the method. It has nothing to do with accessibility of the method. As for the rest of your post, none of it actually _answers_ the question that was asked.

Comment: Yes, I confused it with `static`. I apologize.